# GetCustomPropertyNames does not return all profile fields

Tags: user-profile

I am iterating over users of the same domain and all of the users are assigned the same profile.

```
user.Profile.GetCustomPropertyNames()
```

There are around 50 profile fields but for some users, this method returns only few. Like for some users it just returns 8, for some 32. ..

Why does this happen.

When I check the User Manager, all those users have all those fields. They are empty but even filling them did not change the result.

Should something else be done to read all available profile fields.

using sc8.0 u5

Comment: can you try with user.Profile.RuntimeSettings.Properties[propertyName] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Because a Security Profile Item in "core" is not a Schema

And you're going about it wrong.

### To reach the "schema" for a user

If you want to read all available fields defined for your user, you will have to refer to the *definition* you have defined for your user, which would be the Sitecore Security Profile. And essentially it would involve reading it and looping through the defined fields.  But the Security Profile item in "core" really shouldn't be your guide here; instead YOU define what properties should be shown for any user and go from there.

### To read properties for a user

For the user itself, you will only ever get profile fields and values that have been set on *that specific user*. Changing the Security Profile definition in "core" does *nothing* to update your existing users - it is simply there to give Sitecore a basic UI for user editing. For convenience.

As a side note; the fact that it is stored in "core" should give this away. "Core" is the Sitecore database from which the Sitecore UI runs - nothing else.

### Further

Underneath the Sitecore Profile Provider lies a completely standard ASP.NET Profile Provider. In a very simplified form, `GetPropertyValues` for a user is done by executing the `dbo.aspnet_Profile_GetProperties` Stored Procedure, and then splitting the key/value pairs on `:`.

```
      connectionHolder = SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(this._sqlConnectionString, true);
      this.CheckSchemaVersion(connectionHolder.Connection);
      SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.aspnet_Profile_GetProperties", connectionHolder.Connection);
      sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout;
      sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (object) this.ApplicationName));
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (object) userName));
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(this.CreateInputParam("@CurrentTimeUtc", SqlDbType.DateTime, (object) DateTime.UtcNow));
      sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
      if (sqlDataReader.Read())
      {
        names = sqlDataReader.GetString(0).Split(':');
        values = sqlDataReader.GetString(1);
        int bytes = (int) sqlDataReader.GetBytes(2, 0L, (byte[]) null, 0, 0);
        numArray = new byte[bytes];
        sqlDataReader.GetBytes(2, 0L, numArray, 0, bytes);
```

Notice how this code makes no references to any User Profile "definition" of sorts. At this level; profile attributes are just treated as key/value pairs.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with `user.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Property")`?

And for saving the profile values - you need to add `user.Profile.Save();`

You can refer these articles:
http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2015/08/how-to-store-custom-user-profile.html

Comment: Please note that you need to disclose that it's your own blog your linking to: [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: If it's not your blog, I'd put that in the answer to prevent spam flags